# async_work_group_copy from __constant

Tags: constants, opencl

Code like this:

```
__constant char a[1] = "x";
...
__local char b[1];
async_work_group_copy(b, a, 1, 0);
```

throws a compile error:

```
no instance of overloaded function "async_work_group_copy" matches the argument list
```

So it seems that this function cannot be used to copy from `__constant` address space. Am I right? If yes, what's the preferred method to make a copy of `__constant` data to `__local` memory for faster access? Now I use a simple for loop, where each workitem copies several elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async_work_group_copy()` is defined to copy between local and global memory only (see here: http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/).

As far as I know, there is no method to perform bulk copy from constant to local memory. Maybe the reason is that constant memory is actually cached on all GPUs that I know of, which essentially means that it works at the same speed as local memory.

The `vloadn()` family of functions can load whole vectors for all types of memory, including constant, so that may partially match what you need. However, it is not bulk copy.

Comment: At least on AMD (specifically, Mobility Radeon 5650 HD) constant memory shows much worse speed, than local, when access is performed using random indices, not known at compile time. I've read specifications at khronos and it seemed strange to me, 'cause as I understand constant memory is just a special part of global one (almost the same access throughput confirms that).

Comment: Constant memory is definitely cached, but the cache is sequential, meaning that if you want to read a bunch of values, the reads from the cache will get serialized. So, in general, I would use constant memory only for items that will be shared across work items, in which case there would be only one read from the cache (or 2,4,8,16 if you use the vloadn() function).